# Does cat6 last longer than cat5e with respect to the elements

Tags: ethernet, cable

I am planning to install cat6 outdoors but would like to know if its more robust when exposed to the elements. If not i will continue to use cat5e. Conduit is not an option for me right now, also is outdoor tough Ethernet cabling.

Comment: Only as a side-effect of its better shielding. outdoor cable needs to deal with hazards well beyond the scope of standards for in-wall wiring, so it would be wasteful to ruggedize all CAT-6.

Comment: so your basically saying its not better with respect to the elements then. eg. sun, rain

Comment: that is correct

Comment: thought I should state that while cat6 is not inherently better for outdoor scenarios, I have no idea whether ruggedized CAT6 made specifically for outdoor scenarios isn't better than ruggedized CAT5 made for outdoor use. I wouldn't expect that it would be, but either way, that has nothing to do with the differences between the IEEE CAT5 and CAT6 specifications.

Comment: You also need to be very mindful of running indoor cable outdoors as it does not have grounding (even some outdoor stuff doesn't), and if you are running it any significant distance outdoors you are inviting hardware issues on the interfaces you are connecting to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **cat** rating itself doesn't designate it outside durability.  Cat 6e is slightly thicker and therefore probably 1% more durable, but you need cable designed for outside use.

This cable is specifically designed for outdoor use.
[https://www.amazon.com/Cat6-Outdoor-Shielded-Waterproof-trueCABLE/dp/B01JAVN3Y4/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1506564532&sr=8-3&keywords=cat+6e+outdoor+cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JAVN3Y4)